# Integrating Powermock with kotlin for Instrumentation testing

Tags: android, kotlin, powermock, powermockito, powermockrunner

I am trying to integrate Powermock with Kotlin to test date related logic using Calendar and shared preferences but i am always getting unresolved reference for Powermock but mockito object works fine.

I have tried integrating all the powermock related dependencies i could find but nothing works

Dependencies i have included in my project -

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:2.0.0-beta.5"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5"
testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest:2.0.5"
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.0.0-RC1"
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.11.0'
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0"
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.11.0"
```

I am not sure is i am using the correct versions or missing some dependency.

Comment: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/232

Comment: can't see your code, but did you follow: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito

Comment: @Blundell thanks for the reply. As i suspected it was version compatibility issue.